# AIR main Activity have black overlay when Camera permission present

Tags: android, air, adobe, android-camera

I'm having a problem with native extension I wrote. My native extension simply starts sharing Activity, like this

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
context.getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

The problem is that as soon as I add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

to the application descriptor it puts black overlay over the applications main activity. Or maybe it hides the activity completely, not sure. 
Anyway, as soon as user is done with the sharing activity, app returns to the main activity but it stays black.

The only way to make main AIR activity visible again is by

1. Pressing on/off button to shut device down;
2. Pressing on/off again;
3. Clicking on the screen somewhere.

I haven't done too much development with Android using camera, can someone clarify is this Android related problem, that camera causes activities to run differently, or is this Adobe AIR specific thing?

And maybe any ideas on not leaving users with the black screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In your `Manifest`'s application tag, set `hardwareAccelerated` to `false`.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```

There are several reports of black `Activities` because of `OpenGL`rendering issues with `Adobe Air`.

For example:

https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/changing-focus-text-input-displays.html
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1458707

Comment: I mark this as correct. Even though I was not able to solve the problem this pointed me to the right direction.